# Combining SQL queries into one with various having/group by/where rownum

Tags: sql, oracle

I currently have three ORACLE SQL queries which are similar to this simplified example.

I get a list of customers which fulfill my requirements:

```
CREATE VIEW customerQRY AS
SELECT
   o.customer_id,
   o.order_id,
   si.item_id,
   o.price,
   o.discount
FROM
   Orders o
JOIN StockItems si ON o.order_id = si.order_id
WHERE
   o.returned = 'N'
   AND o.num_items = 1
   AND o.completed = 'Y'
   AND o.order_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-01-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY') AND TO_DATE('01-01-2020', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
;
```

From those I get the top 1000 customers which have bought more than 10 items at max 10% discount:

```
CREATE TABLE CustomerSamples
SELECT
   customer_id
FROM (
   SELECT
      customer_id
   FROM
      customerQRY
   GROUP BY
      customer_id
   HAVING
      COUNT(DISTINCT(order_id)) > 9
      AND discount < 11
   ORDER BY
      COUNT(DISTINCT(order_id)) DESC,
      discount DESC
)
WHERE
   ROWNUM < 1001
;
```

Then I get all the data related to the order and items for this subset of customers:

(edit: this is actually not totally correct: I want the order details here to be a subset of the orders specified in CustomerSamples i.e. the ones which fall into the discount < 11 category; this can be done with a "where" clause here or however defined in a potential single query)

```
SELECT
   Orders.*,
   StockItems.*
FROM
   CustomerSamples cs
JOIN Orders ON Orders.customer_id = cs.customer_id
JOIN StockItems ON StockItems.order_id = Orders.order_id
;
```

(please forgive any missed syntax errors as I've simplified the real ones - these run correctly in reality)

This is fair enough - it works - but I was asked to try and combine this into one query which makes sense for us with running on production boxes etc.
I have gone back and forth trying different things, but can't come up with a sensible solution!
Sure I can literally use customerQry as a subquery in the CustomerSamples, but this means I don't have the data from customerQRY and suddenly things get more complicated. I can't return order_ids from query 2 as we are grouping on the customer and counting the order_ids.

I can't see a way to get the 1000 customer_ids and their related order_ids in one go. I feel like I'm missing an obvious solution here, but I can't see it. Anyone have any ideas? Am I just fighting a waterfall?

Comment: A simple approach is CTEs.  However, if you describe up front the data you are working with and the result set you want, there might be other approaches that simplify the queries rather than just repeating them.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I wasn't aware of (or have just forgotten!) about CTEs, so this is a good shout, thanks. The data I'm using isn't too different to what is described. I want to get the stored data for the orders for the top 1000 customers which fit my requirements specified. I have clarified the question a bit more to specify that the orders should be a subset of what I am specifying for the customers i.e. fall in the <10% discount range, my apologies if it is a bit vague.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the texts of your request, then an example:

```
SELECT
   Orders.*,
   StockItems.*
FROM
   Orders JOIN StockItems ON StockItems.order_id = Orders.order_id
WHERE
   Orders.customer_id in (
      SELECT
         customer_id
      FROM (
         SELECT
            customer_id
         FROM
            (
               SELECT
                  o.customer_id,
                  o.order_id,
                  si.item_id,
                  o.price,
                  o.discount
               FROM
                  Orders o
               JOIN StockItems si ON o.order_id = si.order_id
               WHERE
                  o.returned = 'N'
                  AND o.num_items = 1
                  AND o.completed = 'Y'
                  AND o.order_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-01-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY') AND TO_DATE('01-01-2020', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
            )
         GROUP BY
            customer_id
         HAVING
            COUNT(DISTINCT(order_id)) > 9
            AND discount < 11
         ORDER BY
            COUNT(DISTINCT(order_id)) DESC,
            discount DESC
      )
      WHERE
         ROWNUM < 1001)
;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice solution. I was obsessed with just focusing on combining the first two tables I only got part way to this. Orders is a massive table so I was wondering if I'd missed a simpler method to not have to go through it twice, but it seems potentially unavoidable.
I realised upon reading this that I had missed a requirement for the orders returned to match the requirements of the "having" clause, ie have a discount < 11.  Apologies for not being clear enough! That is not a big deal as it can be added to the outer "where".